# Sum the number of elements in ALL arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sum

I've a collection with a field "pax".
pax is an array.

I would like to have the **total sum** of all pax in my collection.

I found how to display number of pax for each line (using aggregate and size) but it's not exactly my point

[image: example of pax]
in this example, the size is 2 and I would like to sum this with the rest of all other lines in my DB.

Comment: can you share input data and output data at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you're looking to achieve something like this:

```
[
  {
    "sum": 3
  }
]
```

which can be done with this aggregation:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "sum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$size": "$pax"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thank you very much it solves my problem !

I've a question linked to this request : is it possible in this request to add another filter ( like created :{ $gte : new ISODate("2018-12-31T20:15:31Z")} ), but not sure where to put it.

If I need to post it in a new question, no problem, I will.

Comment: @David if `created` is an attribute in root document, I guess you should add your condition in a `$match` before the `$group`

Comment: will try this. Thanks !